# how to create a many to many relation in prisma

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am working on a diving academy website. I am using prisma to connect to mongoDB.
I'm new to backend, here is the problem I'm facing.

1. I have a user model, their role property could be either user or coach and they could be teaching in a course or as a student in a course.
   For example, I have userA is a coach and userB is a normal user. userB joined the courseC which is taught by userA.
2. user can add product to favorite or cart. Product only created by admin. Am I doing it right?

Here is my code:

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  hasedPassword String?
  role          String    @default("user")
  numOfDive     Int?
  level         String?
  certificate   String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt

  accounts             Account[]
  favorites            Product[]
  carts                Product[]
  courseAsInstructorId String?   @db.ObjectId
  asInstructor         Course?   @relation(fields: [courseAsInstructorId], references: [id])
  courseAsStudentId    String?   @db.ObjectId
  asStudent            Course?   @relation(fields: [courseAsStudentId], references: [id])
  // prisma automatically add below 4 lines when I save
  Course               Course?   @relation(fields: [courseId], references: [id])
  courseId             String?   @db.ObjectId
  Course               Course?   @relation(fields: [courseId], references: [id])
  courseId             String?   @db.ObjectId

}

// FOR SOCIAL LOGIN
model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?
  user              User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Course {
  id                String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name              String?
  totalNumOfStudent Int      @default(4)
  available         Int      @default(4)
  startDate         DateTime
  endDate           DateTime
  price             Int
  createdAt         DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime @updatedAt

  instructorIds String[] @db.ObjectId
  instructors   User[]   @relation("instructors", fields: [instructorIds], references: [id])
  studentIds    String[] @db.ObjectId
  students      User[]   @relation("studens", fields: [studentIds], references: [id])

  // prisma add below automatically
  User User[]
  User User[]
}

model Product {
  id            String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String
  size          String[]
  color         String
  stock         Int      @default(0)
  price         Int
  previousPrice Int?
  gender        String
  category      String
  images        Image[]
  createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt
  User          User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String?  @db.ObjectId
}

type Image {
  mobile  MobileImage?
  desktop DesktopImage
}

type MobileImage {
  url String
  publicId String
}

type DesktopImage{
  url String
  publicId String
}
```

Comment: Your User model looks fine but i think you have duplicates where you are defining the Course fields. You can also leverage enums for the role field instead of using String type.